# Adding varying values to a list inside of a Concurrent Dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, thread-safety

I have decimals that I'm trying to add to a list inside of a `ConcurrentDictionary`

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<decimal>> fullList =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<decimal>>();

public void AddData(string key, decimal value)
{
    if (fullList.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        var partialList = fullList[key];
        partialList.Add(value);
    }
    else
    {
        fullList.GetOrAdd(key, new List<decimal>() { value });
    }
}
```

Technically the above code works for me but it was only done that way because I didn't know how to do the `GetOrAdd` method for both adding and updating. My question is how do I use that method for both considering that my updating would be adding an item to the end of an existing list?

Comment: Be aware that the `AddData` is not thread-safe. If two threads call it with the same `key` at the same time, the behavior will be undefined. The `List` class is not thread-safe.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias to be fully thread safe I would need to create a ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<decimal>> instead?

Comment: Yeap. Or even better `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<decimal>>`. The `ConcurrentBag` is a very specialized class (it's only good in In mixed producer-consumer scenarios). People often think that it's the closest type to a thread-safe `List`, but it's not. For reference: [When to use a thread-safe collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/when-to-use-a-thread-safe-collection)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm new to the multi threaded aspect in C# as you can probably tell but I should specify that I'm adding to the dictionary in one thread and reading from it in another so I'm not sure what scenario that would put me in. Do you still recommend the concurrent queue over the concurrent bag?

Comment: Yeap, your scenario is pure producer-consumer, not mixed, so the `ConcurrentQueue` will perform better than the `ConcurrentBag`. Mixed producer-consumer scenarios, where the same thread acts both as producer and consumer, are very rare. Personally I've never seen or needed one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `AddOrUpdate` method for that purpose, as below:

```
fullList.AddOrUpdate(key, 
                     new List<decimal>() { value }, 
                     (key,list) => 
                     { 
                         list.Add(value); 
                         return list; 
                     });
```

Essentially, when the `key` is *missing* a new list is created with only one element, `value`. Otherwise, we add to the list associated with the current `key`, the `value` and we return the list.

For documentation of this method, please have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_AddOrUpdate__0_System_Func__0__1__System_Func__0__1__1__).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? Hope it helps.

```
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<decimal>> fullList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<decimal>>();
    public void AddData(string key, decimal value)
    {
        List<decimal> list;
        if (!fullList.TryGetValue(key, out list))
        {
            list = new List<decimal>();
            fullList.GetOrAdd(key, list);
        }
        list.Add(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to invoke the `GetOrAdd` in all cases:

```
public void AddData(string key, decimal value)
{
    var partialList = fullList.GetOrAdd(key, _ => new List<decimal>());
    lock (partialList) partialList.Add(value); // Lock for thread safety
}
```

When you use a `ConcurrentDictionary` you should strive towards its special concurrent API that enforces the atomicity of operations. Checking and adding in two steps (`ContainsKey`+`Add`) is not atomic, it introduces a race condition, and could compromise the correctness of your application.